# SharePoint Online - Generate an icon via Column Formatting?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a list in SPO with a Choice column (Video, Word, PDF). I would like to display an icon in a column called `FileType`.

I have tried to customize the JSON of the `FileType` Column but it just shows the text.

Any ideas?

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgLightGray sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-LightGrayFont"
  },
  "txtContent": "=if([$FileType] == 'Video', 'MSNVideos', if([$FileType] == 'Word', 'WordDocument', if([$FileType] == 'PDF', 'PDF','')))"
}
```

Comment: This just gives blank in the FabricIcon Column ... `{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if([$FileType] == 'PDF', 'PDF', if([$FileType] == 'Video', 'MSNVideos', if([$FileType] == 'Word', 'WordDocument')))"
    },
    "style": {
        "font-size": "24px",
        "color": "black"
    }
}`

Comment: Hi @PeteWhelan, did you try solution given below? Is it working for you?

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this JSON for your column JSON formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "iconName": "=if([$FileType] == 'PDF', 'PDF', if([$FileType] == 'Video', 'MSNVideos', if([$FileType] == 'Word', 'WordDocument','')))"
  },
  "style": {
    "font-size": "24px",
    "color": "black"
  }
}
```

Where `FileType` is internal name of your SharePoint list choice column. You can get the exact internal name of your SharePoint list column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I have tested JSON codes provided by Ganesh Sanap and they work well. Please replace with right internal name of columns.